# Rotate vertex label

Tags: r, plot, igraph

When plotting a graph using igraph package, how to rotate the vertex label in the plot, for example, by pi/4?

```
library(igraph)
g = graph.ring(5)
V(g)$name = paste(LETTERS[1:5], 'rotate_45')
plot.igraph(vertex.label.rotate=pi/2, g ) ##this doesn't work
```

Comment: `plot.igraph(vertex.label.degree = pi/2, g )` Maybe?

Comment: @DavidArenburg `vertex.label.degree: The position of the label in relation to the vertex, where 0 is right, “pi” is left, “pi/2” is below, and “-pi/2” is above.` It's position, not the orientation of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible in igraph directly. However, by specifying a layout we can retrieve the coordinates of the vertices and add a rotated text.

```
library(igraph)
g = graph.ring(5)
V(g)$name = paste(LETTERS[1:5], 'rotate_45')

#add layout to have coordinates where we can plot the vertices labels later
coords <- layout_(g, in_circle())

plot.igraph(g, layout = coords,  vertex.label = "", rescale = F)

angles = c(45, 45, 45, 135, 77)

#Apply the text labels with angle as srt
for (i in 1:dim(coords)[1]) {
  text(x = coords[i,1], y = coords[i,2], labels = V(g)$name[i], 
       col = "black", srt = angles[i], xpd = T)
}
```

This results in:
[image]

If you want to provide radians instead, you could use before specifying the angles

```
rad2deg <- function(rad) {(rad * 180) / (pi)}
```